# loading large csv files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I had csv files of size 6GB and I tried using the import function on Matlab to load them but it failed due to memory issue. Is there a way to reduce the size of the files?

I think the no. of columns are causing the problem. I have a 133076 rows by 2329 columns. I had another file which is of the same no. of rows but only 12 rows and Matlab could handle that. However, once the columns increases, the files got really big.

Ulitmately, if I can read the data column wise so that I can have 2329 column vector of 133076, that will be great.

I am using Matlab 2014a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric data are by default stored by Matlab in double precision format, which takes up 8 bytes per number. Data of size 133076 x 2329 therefore take up 2.3 GiB in memory. Do you have that much free memory? If not, reducing the file size won't help.

If the problem is not that the data themselves don't fit into memory, but is really about the process of reading such a large csv-file, then maybe using the [syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)

```
M = csvread(filename,R1,C1,[R1 C1 R2 C2])
```

might help, which allows you to only read part of the data at one time. Read the data in chunks and assemble them in a (preallocated!) array.

If you do not have enough memory, another possibility is to read chunkwise and then convert each chunk to [single precision](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) before storing it. This reduces memory consumption by a factor of two.

And finally, if you don't process the data all at once, but can implement your algorithm such that it uses only a few rows or columns at a time, that same syntax may help you to avoid having all the data in memory at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But do u happen to use python and had tried pandas?

Comment: @AKSG, no, sorry I don't.